# I get an exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when I instantiate a new XPWFDocument object

Tags: java, exception, apache-poi

I have a java program which contains the below code:

```
try{
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(input);
} catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Exception thrown.");
}
```

in a certain method which has handles the necessary exception with a proper catch statement. However when I run this program I get an error/exception in console as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTHdrFtr
```

I have downloaded the Apache POI library from this [link](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/poi/dev/bin/poi-bin-3.15-beta2-20160702.tar.gz) which is there in this [page](https://poi.apache.org/download.html). (I believe this is the official Apache's POI download page) I am using Eclipse IDE and I've added the library to the build path. Why am I getting this exception? Is there something missing in the library?

Comment: Did you [try reading the Apache POI FAQ on this topic?](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025) And did you try following the advice given in [the answer to that FAQ?](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025)

Comment: I have not gone through this link. Let me take a look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific class referred to by the exception is contained in poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15-beta2.jar. You must ensure that the 'poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15-beta2.jar' jar file which is contained in the tar.gz is in your build path and will be included in the application's classpath once built.